# Django Nginx 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0

Tags: python, django, nginx

> systemd[6181]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission
> denied
>
> systemd[6181]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning
> /home/neggo/venv/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied

Залил проект на сервер, но в итоге получаю ошибку 502.

Сделал диагностику и оказалось **gunicorn** не работает. Разрешение давал 710

Делал по [инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file)

Comment: у тебя и nginx запущен от твоего имени, и gunicorn?

Comment: под тем юзером под которым запускается gunicorn не может запуститься, нет прав

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверь сокет файл

```
$ sudo systemctl status nginx
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]